# iTunes Connect - Build doesn't appear (even with same version number and app bundle id)

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

On iTunes Connect website, under build, I have no plus sign. My builds are not appearing.

Version number in the general tab (for the heck of it, build number too) are the same as in my iTunes Connect profile.

I archived an ipa in xcode 7.2 and uploaded to appstore successfully. However it does not appear in the app profile I created under build.

I also used the independent iTunes Connect app which also uploaded the ipa successfully, but it also does not appear in build section on website.

Any ideas what could be causing this issue?

Comment: try to upload  build again with same version If it throws error "already build was there " wait OR try to upload with another build version

Answer (score 2):

iTunesConnect could be slow and buggy at times.

I encountered the same issue. Couldn't see it for 30+ minutes. Turned off my laptop, went to bed and the next morning it was there.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Its been 24 hours since the first time I uploaded it.

Answer (score 0):

There will be having some issues with your uploaded build so you can just make appeal to App store technical team with your **app id**.

They will provide you guide and reason for not showing your build into itunesconnect.

Comment: where would i submit an appeal regarding this issue?

Comment: go on this link https://developer.apple.com/contact/ in that go App Store section and click on app review link.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice. I never contacted Apple, but after 48 hours Apple finally contacted me via email saying that there are swift files that are not supported.

Wonderful. Thanks apple. Personal opinion: should have stayed with Objective-C. But I guess that solves the issue why it was not displaying under the build section on iTunes Connect.